# how to add micrometer tags to webClient in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, micrometer, spring-micrometer

So I am collecting a metric like this
http_client_requests_seconds_count{clientname="www.exmaple.com", uri="/users/somethihng/1233"}
from my spring application using micrometer and exposing it to prometheus.

Now i didnt configured any of these metric's label/tags, this is provided by default with webClient metrics. Now 10s of such `http_client metrics` from my appliction are being collected  but I want to add some specific tags to a particular webClient call (FYI: I have a separate webClient instance for making this call).

How can I add tags to metrics which is being collected from this one webClient ?
I have come across `WebFluxTagsProvider` and `RouterFunctionMetrics` but couldnt find appropriate code examples.

Also, i know how to add global common tags, question is about adding tags for a specific webClient calls.

Would really appreciate the help. Also, if you ned clarity on the question please post a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `MetricsWebClientCustomizer`, it is provided when WebClient is build

Comment: Sure, will give this a try. Can you share any code snippet for its implementation?